# angularjs $http success data parameter doesn't return the right object

Tags: json, angularjs, servlets, post

I am using $http to POST an angularjs variable, I do receive the JSON equivalent in servlet's doPost method. When I write a JSON in the response from the servlet, $http.success(data, status, header, config) is called. But when I assign 'data' to an angularjs variable, no value get's assigned to the variable. Tried using JSON.parse(data) but of no use. Following is the code snippet.

AngularJS

```
$scope.result = {
    title: "",
    subject: "",
    summary: "",
    body: "",
    extra: ""
};

$http.post(url, JSON.stringify(obj)).
success(function(data, status, headers, config){
        $scope.result = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log("data: " + data);
        console.log("status: " + status);
        console.log("headers: " + headers);
        console.log("config: " + config);
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config){
        $scope.result = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log("data: " + data);
        console.log("status: " + status);
        console.log("headers: " + headers);
        console.log("config: " + config);
    });
```

Console output on receiving the response is as follows

```
data: [object Object]
status: 200 
headers: function (name) {
   if (!headersObj) headersObj =  parseHeaders(headers);

   if (name) {
      return headersObj[lowercase(name)] || null;
   }

   return headersObj;
  }
config: [object Object]
```

Following is the code snippet from the servlet.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        System.out.println("doPost called");
        response.getWriter().write("{"title":"Transaction Status","subject":"Congratulations!!","summary":"Successfully received your request, below is your Transaction ID","body":"5a85fc3b303d47dca6514b707442f2cd","extra":"Please save this transaction ID for future reference"}");
    }
```

I am not able to obtain the JSON sent from doPost() method in angularjs success function. Is it the correct way of doing it?
Angularjs automatically converts the received JSON to javascript object type, so I must be able to assign 'data' straight to $scope.result.

It will be great if someone can please point me in right direction.

Comment: `data` is an object containing a property `data`. That property holds what you want. You may want to rename `data` to something like `response`. If you do, you could assign `response.data` (without using `JSON.parse()`

Comment: I tried your recommendation, following is the console output.

    response: undefined
    status: 200
    headers: function (name) {
        if (!headersObj) headersObj =  parseHeaders(headers);
    
        if (name) {
          return headersObj[lowercase(name)] || null;
        }
    
        return headersObj;
      } common.js:113
    config: [object Object]

Comment: In your success function, add `console.dir(data)` and add the response to your question please

Comment: console.dir printed out the entire object and this is what I found in it.

"body: "cb309b8454464a0e90b4aea3ecb7372c"
extra: "Please save this transaction ID for future reference"
subject: "Congratulations!!"
summary: "Successfully received your request, below is your Transaction ID"
title: "Transaction Status"

Million thanks for the help, it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$http.post(url, $.param(obj), {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
    }
})
```

If you do not want to use jQuery $.param, you can use an alternative

```
$http.post(url, obj, {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
    },
    transformRequest: function(obj) {
        var str = [];
        for(var p in obj)
        str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
        return str.join("&");
    }
})
```

Comment: May I ask what that is supposed to do?

Comment: To send data as form data instead of request payload

Comment: Which method is `queryparams` referencing?

Comment: Edit: queryparams was a mistake